# Tomcat 8 - Maven + Spring + Hibernate - Error with oracle datasource

Tags: java, tomcat, oracle11g, datasource, tomcat8

I have a maven project . I'm trying to config tomcat 8 with oracle 11g. I've inserted ojdbc6.jar in tomcat/lib. I already have inserted ojdbc6.jar in maven dependencies.

This is my configuration:

context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/ph"
          global="jdbc/ph"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

server.xml

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/ph" global="jdbc/ph" auth="Container"               
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1521:ORC11"
      username="user" password="pass"
      maxTotal="20" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>DB Connection</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/ph</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/ph</property>
   <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

SessionFactory

```
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
   StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
   serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
   ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
   sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

When i run, i obtain always these errors:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:213) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.beginTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.MySessionDao.getSession(PhSessionDao.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
... 40 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.30]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar:5.0.5.Final]
... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:524) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:493) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.30]
... 58 common frames omitted
```

Thanks

Comment: NEVER edit or paraphrase the stack trace. Post the ENTIRE stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't loading your JDBC Driver or the connection URL:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
```

in your hibernate.cfx.xml and make sure you have ojdbc14.jar added